# Change query response array value using MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB. I have created query in MongoDB using PHP. My query is as follows:

```js
$date_start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2016-06-08T18:30:00.000Z"));
$default_date = new MongoDate(strtotime("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"));
$pipeline = array(
  array('$project' => array(
    'MainsPower' => 1,
    'EventTS' => 1
  )),
  array('$unwind' => array(
    'path' => '$MainsPower',
    'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
    'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
  )),
  array('$match' => array(
    '$and' => array(
      //array('EventTS' => array('$gt' => $date_start)),
      //array('PanelID' => 'A00911'),
      array("MainsPower" => array('$ne' => null))
    )
  )),
  array(
    '$project' => array(
      'MainsPower' => 1,
      '_id' => 0,
      'EventTS' => array(
        '$add' => array(
          array('$subtract' => array('$EventTS', $default_date)),
          array('$multiply' => array(60000, '$arrayIndex'))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
);
$result = $collection - > aggregate($pipeline);
```

Output of query is as below

```js
Array
  (
    [0] => Array(
      [EventTS] => 1497033900000[MainsPower] => 204
    )

    [1] => Array(
      [EventTS] => 1497034800000[MainsPower] => 204
    )

    [2] => Array(
      [EventTS] => 1497035700000[MainsPower] => 204
    )
  )
```

But, I want output as below because while plotting graph I need data in below format I searched many solution and I tried to apply the same but failed to get records in required format

```js
Array
  (
    [0] => Array(
      [1497033900000, 204]
    )

    [1] => Array(
      [1497034800000, 204]
    )

    [2] => Array(
      [1497035700000, 204]
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below code:**

```
$formattedResponse = array();
    foreach($mongoOutput as $out){
       $formattedResponse[] = array($out["EventTS"],$out["MainsPower"]);
    }
```

- where mongoOutput is the default output you are getting from mongo, and formattedResponse is the variable in which you will get the output in desired format.

Please change variable names as per your needs.

Comment: Thnaks for your respponse.
as records are more than 50 thousand so i can not use foreach  loop because code breaks in loop or it takes longer time to respond

Kindly suggest something in query of mongoDB such that processing is done by mongoDB and respond  in required formate

Comment: You cannot change the format in which data is returned from mongo / mysql driver. This processing has to be done at any level(mongo cursor level, php level, JS level) if you want that in the desired format. Better than that you can change the graph plotting system to accept data in the format received from mongo